# FreeBSD nat via PF: how to change from random UDP ports to incremental?

Tags: freebsd, nat, pf

I'm testing NAT penetration code and need a symmetric NAT. I have configured FreeBSD with PF, very simple rule:

```
# rl0 in WAN on DHCP, sk0 is LAN with computers behind this NAT.
nat on rl0 from sk0:network to any -> (rl0)
```

This works great, NAT is symmetric for UDP packets, but, unfortunately, outgoing port number is random for each packet to different destination. Is it a way to configure PF so ports will be not random, but kind of incremental? For example, UDP packet to host A will get outgoing UDP port number 50000, UDP packet to host B will get port number 50001, to host C 50002 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static-port` option should do what you want.

> With nat rules, the static-port option prevents pf(4) from modifying the source port on TCP and UDP packets.

Thus giving you a rule of.

```
nat on rl0 from sk0:network to any -> (rl0) static-port
```

I'm curious as to why you would want to do this though. Port randomisation isn't such a bad thing and can go some way to protecting vulnerable protocols. Like the Kaminsky DNS issues of last year, for example.

Comment: This will force port to be always the same for single computer behind NAT :(. So this effectively degrades symmetric nat to cone nat. Is it any way not to make port static, but just to change the way port is generated? (from random to incremental)

Comment: It's not a configuration feature and I think you'd have a hard time convincing PF's authors that it's a good thing to have. PF is of course BSD licensed though, so there's always the DIY avenue.

Comment: Maybe you know any other software NAT for unix/linux/windows that can create "symmetric nat" with incremental outgoing port assignment? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you can try

```
# sysctl net.inet.ip.portrange.randomized=0
```